# How to get Braintree Drop-In UI to work with MVC PartialView using Sammy.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, braintree, sammy.js

I am trying to integrate the Braintree Payments Drop-In UI on an MVC page that uses Sammy.js with MVC PartialViews to swap the DOM seamlessly when navigating my site.

The issue I run into is that even though I have placed the script tag to load braintree.js and then run the Braintree.setup() function at the end of my page as suggested on the docs, I get the error:

```
Reference Error: braintree not defined
```

The code I am using is:

```
<div id="payment-form"></div>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
    var clientToken = "@ViewData("BraintreeClientToken")";
    braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
       container: "payment-form"
    });
</script>
```

This code works perfectly when copied and pasted into a web forms page (only changing the ViewData call to use a public form variable).

I have tried moving the Braintree.setup() call into a separate function that is coded to run after the sammy.js swap has been confirmed to have finished and I receive the same error.

**EDIT:**  The below attempt works after Chiapa noticed that Visual Studio had reformatted my code to make the "B" in braintree.setup() uppercase.  Changing to lowercase allows that code to work.  However, the more straightforward logic above still does not work after ensuring the correct casing of the function call.

<strike>I also tried loading the braintree.js script in that after-swap code via the following:</strike>

```
var btSuccess = function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    Braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "payment-form"
    });
}
jQuery.getScript("https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js", btSuccess);
```

This gives me the following, different error:

```
TypeError: Braintree.setup is not a function
```

I know that the getScript function does not necessarily guarantee the script will have finished execution when it calls the success callback function.  However, even adding a setTimeout(10000) inside the btSuccess function to give it 10 seconds to execute does nothing to change the error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `braintree.setup`, in lowercase?

Comment: So, at what point are you now? Edit your question or create a new one if the changes alter this one completely

Comment: I added an official answer noting this earlier.  I have now edited the post to clarify which of the two scenarios now work.

Comment: Just to clarify, you changed the upper to lower case and it worked. but in your EDIT you still wrote `Braintree` upper case and the error `Braintree.setup is not a function` should have braintree lower case too. Also, have you tried `<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>` instead of `jQuery.getScript("https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js", btSuccess);`?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had lowered the casing of the first scenario in my edit.  Apparently that got lost somewhere.  I also did a strikethrough of the "fixed" portion of the question to show what was still remaining

Comment: There have been enough changes and dialogue on this that I can't follow what the problem is any more. I would recommend [contacting Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) to resolve this issue.  (If all else fails, possibly open a new question with your current problem in it.)

Answer (score 0):

So, Chiapa pointed out something subtle I had missed, and this partially answers the question.

Apparently Visual Studio 2015 reformatted the code when I copied and pasted it from the working web forms page to the script file where I ran the jQuery.getScript() call. It was appropriately lowercase in the web forms page.  I'm guessing this happened because the script file did not have the braintree code in it itself, so it assumed the B in braintree should be capitalized.

So, now with that change my second example does indeed work, where I have to use jQuery.getScript() and an onSuccess callback.

However, that still does not fix the more straightforward question of why it is still getting the "Reference Error: braintree is not defined" when loaded directly on the PartialView, when all the other scripts on that PartialView work.